# Ionic - npm is not recognized as an interal command, even with npm installed

Tags: node.js, cordova, ionic-framework

I am running into a bit of trouble installing a couple ionic cordova native plugins.

Basically if I type `npm` in my cmd I get the npm cli, if I type `ionic` I get the ionic cli, if I type `cordova` I get the cordova cli but:

If I type `ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-camera`

I get
Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:        'C:\WINDOWS\system32\npm' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

C:\WINDOWS\system32\npm is not in my enviroment var path nor is nodejs or npm installed there, so why would the ionic cli look for it there?

Comment: try "sudo npm install" command

Comment: Try using `ionic` only without `cordova`.

Answer (score 1):

With Ionic the version of npm is very sensitive. Not all npm versions work, especially the latest (which ever) always give me troubles.

1. npm i -g npm@5.0.4 (or try a few others if this one breaks)
2. Deleting/renaming your package-lock.json makes the occasional difference.
3. Delete node_modules and retype npm install

Those 3 work for me.

Answer (score 0):

## Download node.js

First of all Download and install node.js from here [Nodejs.org](https://nodejs.org/en/)

## In windows 10

1. Go to **My Computer** properties

2. Click **Advanced system settings**

3. Now you are on System Properties window, Click **advanced**

4. Then, click **Environment Variable** button

5. From System Variable, Select Path

6. click **Edit**

7. At the end of the Variable value, add **;C:\Program Files\node.js\**

8. Click **Ok** all the open dialogue box

###### Reference: **[Fix ~ npm not recognized as internal or external command](https://all-com-science.blogspot.com/2021/08/Fix%20%20npm%20not%20recognized.html)** (Note: this is my own blog[include images also)